# limit eclipse from taking over the RAM

Tags: eclipse, ram, memory-usage

I'm using Eclipse in Ubuntu 14.04 for scientific stuff and my code consumes a lot of RAM. When I run my code in Eclipse, I see in System Monitor that the RAM usage goes up to almost 100% and at the same moments the OS gets very unresponsive (for example, to open a terminal will take more than a minute). Is there a way to limit the amount of RAM used by eclipse so the OS will remain always responsive?

Thanks!

Comment: You can *maybe* (not sure if this is possible and not at all how to do it) tell Ubuntu to put your self-coded application's memory pages to swap instead of system ones. This will slow down the application though. You have to word your question differently then though, I'd recommend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run an application in eclipse, it creates a separate thread in the OS. The RAM usage of that thread cannot be controlled by eclipse.

One way to avoid your system from crashing is to increase the swap partition size. Even in this case the system gets very sluggish but does not crash.

There are other ways to control the ram usage of an application, say kill the program when the usage goes beyond a certain value. If you set such hard limits on memory usage, then you might run into some unpredictable behaviour/crashes. See the links below that talk about limiting RAM usage.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44985/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26860822/how-limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process-and-not-kill-the-process

I would recommend trying to optimize your code to make it use less ram or think of some way to dump the data to hard disk and read it when required instead of retaining it in RAM. Even better is to increase the RAM!

Comment: There must be a general way to limit the amount of RAM for a given process. The swap memory doesn't even get 50% full.

Comment: I have added more to my original answer

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/pshved/timeout) is a Perl script for exactly this problem.

> ### INTRODUCTION
>
> The timeout script is a resource monitoring program for limiting time and memory consumption of black-boxed processes under Linux. It runs a command you specify in the command line and watches for its memory and time consumption, interrupting the process if it goes out of the limits, and notifying the user with the preset message.
>
> The killer feature of this script (and, actually, the reason why it appeared) is that it not only watches the process spawned directly, but also keeps track of its subsequently forked children. You may choose if the scope of the watched processes is constrained by process group or by the process tree.

<sub>[Source](https://github.com/pshved/timeout/blob/master/README)</sub>